# Where to locate Symfony project created in Vagrant?

Tags: symfony, vagrant, homestead, vagrant-windows

Hey guys I'm new to vagrant. I have used Homestead box. I have created Symfony4 Project but seems I can't locate the project folder..

Create Project In.

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton Symfony-Demo
```

Homestead.yaml Config

```
folders:
- map: C:\homestead
  to: /home/vagrant/homestead     

sites:
- map: Symfony-Demo.test
  to: /home/vagrant/Symfony-Demo/public
  type: symfony4
```

Symfony-Demo.test is running well in browser.

```
Your application is now ready. You can start working on it at:
/home/vagrant/Symfony-Demo/
```

The problem is I don't know where the project is located..  C:\homestead is just empty..

Answer (score 0):

Folder sharing in windows is just tricky...

- did you first create the folder on windows?  vagrant guest reads what's on the host, not the other way around as usually implied in the doc
- did you switch to using winRM, which is a lot more efficient for windows?
- are you kicking up vagrant from a command window run as administrator?  are you using an administrator-level account to log in to winRM?

Comment: Yes, I created folder in windows, but didn't do anything like winrm, switching in admin mode..